# Console output to listview

Tags: c#, listview, console

How can I list the console output to a a listview in Visual Studio? Code I have is

```
foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
{
if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

    Console.WriteLine("Block blob of length {0}: {1}", blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri);

}
else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
{
    CloudPageBlob pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob)item;

    Console.WriteLine("Page blob of length {0}: {1}", pageBlob.Properties.Length, pageBlob.Uri);

}
else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
{
    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;

    Console.WriteLine("Directory: {0}", directory.Uri);
}
```

}

I can't see the results as it is a windows form

Comment: You can use the 'as' operator to make your code more readable and slightly improve performance (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Winforms application, why are you sending results to the console?

You could add `List<string> results = new List<string>();` to start of the code above, then replace each `Console.WriteLine` with `results.Add`. Finally use code like this to display the results:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string s in results)
    {
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append(s);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Results");
```

or, if you have a ListView:

```
foreach (string s in results)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(s);
}
```